# Thread sync by using mutex and barrier in C

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mutex, barrier

I am trying to use pthread mutex variables and barrier to synchronize the output of my program, but it is not working the way I want it to. Each thread is seeing its final value every 20 values (coming from the for loop) which is alright but I'm trying to make them all get to the same final value (if using 5 threads, all of them should see 100 as final value, with 4 threads, 80, etc)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int SharedVariable =0;
void *SimpleThread(void *args)
{
    int num,val,rc;
    int which =(int)args;
    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    for(num=0; num<20; num++){
#ifdef PTHREAD_SYNC
        if(random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
            usleep(10);
#endif
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %d sees value %d\n", which, val);
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        SharedVariable = val+1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    }   
    val=SharedVariable;

    printf("Thread %d sees final value %d\n", which, val);
    //pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1);
    //pthread_exit((void*) 0);
    //pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(atoi(argv[1]) > 0){        
   int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);  
   //pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);
   pthread_t threads[num_threads];
   int rc;
   long t;
   rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
   for(t=0; t< num_threads; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, SimpleThread, (void* )t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }

    //pthread_join(thread1);

   }
    rc= pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
}
   else{
      printf("ERROR: The parameter should be a valid positive number.");
      exit(-1);
  }

   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex1);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a barrier (`pthread_barrier_wait()`) before checking for the final value - this ensures that no thread will proceed until all threads have reached the barrier.

In addition, you should be calling `pthread_join()` to wait for the threads to finish, and you only need to hold the mutex around the increment:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_barrier_t barrier1;

int SharedVariable = 0;

void *SimpleThread(void *args)
{
    int num,val;
    int which = (int)args;

    for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
#ifdef PTHREAD_SYNC
        if(random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
            usleep(10);
#endif
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        val = SharedVariable;
        printf("*** thread %d sees value %d\n", which, val);
        SharedVariable = val + 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier1);

    val = SharedVariable;
    printf("Thread %d sees final value %d\n", which, val);
    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num_threads = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;

    if (num_threads > 0) {
        pthread_t threads[num_threads];
        int rc;
        long t;

        rc = pthread_barrier_init(&barrier1, NULL, num_threads);

        if (rc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_barrier_init: %s\n", strerror(rc));
            exit(1);
        }

        for (t = 0; t < num_threads; t++) {
            printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, SimpleThread, (void* )t);
            if (rc) {
                printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                exit(-1);
            }
        }

        for (t = 0; t < num_threads; t++) {
            pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR: The parameter should be a valid positive number.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when it reads the argv[1] and it starts with a number it will read that first number and ignore the rest, like "3sdfsdf" will create 3 threads. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @fgualda87: Use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` - it will tell you the first character after the converted number, which you can use to see if the entire string was valid.  If this isn't clear enough, ask this as another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the `pthread_mutext_unlock(&mutext1)` out of the for loop in your `SimpleThread`. You lock once and unlock mutiple(20) times in your original code.

Alternatively, you could move `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutext1)` into the for loop, just before you read and modify your `SharedVariable`. In this case, each thread's `add-by-one` operation may not consecutive but each thread will get the correct final value.

And before you read the final value of the `SharedVariable`, use a barrier to wait all the threads finish their job.